Viability of a Planet Orbiting a K-type Star (S type orbit) with a White Dwarf Companion
Viability of a Planet Orbiting a K-type Star with a White Dwarf Companion
I'm working on a world-building scenario and am curious about the viability and specifics of the following setup:

Binary System: A binary star system composed of a K-type main sequence star and a white dwarf.
Planetary Orbit: A planet orbits the K-type star within its habitable (Goldilocks) zone.
White Dwarf Radiation: The white dwarf emits enough UV radiation to be impactful, requiring humans on the planet to wear protective eyewear and sunscreen, but the radiation isn't catastrophic to life.
Changing White Dwarf Position: The relative position of the white dwarf to the planet changes over time, meaning the white dwarf rises and sets at different times, similar to how a moon orbits a planet. This rules out scenarios where the planet is in a resonance position (e.g., at a Lagrange point) or where the stars are too close together for significant positional variation.

Questions:

Is this setup possible in terms of astrophysics?
If so, what could be the possible ranges of distances between the stars and the planet to maintain such conditions?

I'm particularly interested in how the system dynamics would allow for the changing position of the white dwarf in the sky and the implications for the planet's habitability.

Hello and Welcome to Worldbuilding! I'd like to point out that this kind of question is likely to get flagged as your setup is a little vague and open to interpretation; it would also probably get flagged as you have multiple questions.

TL;DR - Probably won't work
I had to do a lot of n-body problem mathematics for this; as you have multiple celestial objects here; this implicitly makes any system unstable for long periods of time, but in any case; let's work it out:

Your Main Sequence star is K-type; which generally have a mass between 0.6M☉ to 0.9M☉. (Generally a radius of 0.6☉ to 0.8☉)
Your secondary stellar object is a White Dwarf; which can have a mass between 0.17 M☉ to 1.33 M☉ (though most have a mass between 0.5☉ and 0.7☉)

Problems:

You have not defined the distances between the two stellar objects; but considering the planet is in a S-type orbit, the two stars would be pretty far away (far enough that stellar material can coalesce into a planet)
The White Dwarf star is a remnant of a dead star that was previously on the Main Sequence; but not every star type makes a White Dwarf, only those stars with a mass less than 15.0M☉ (Some sources say this could be as low as 8.0M☉)
Depending on the mass of your White Dwarf star as it was in the Main Sequence lifespan; it would have to be on the upper end of that to be a White Dwarf while the primary star is still in its Main Sequence; which means it would have been something like Sirius B or hotter. This means that the K-Type star would be orbiting the other star initially; as the other star would have been much larger in mass.
Regardless of your planet's size; the previous issues means that it would likely have not formed around the K-type star at all, but its much larger partner star; as it would have gravitationally attracted more material than its smaller stellar partner (not to say it's impossible); if this was the case; then not only would your planet most likely have been irradiated when the star exited the Main Sequence into the Red Giant Branch and Asymptotic Giant Branch before collapsing into a White Dwarf; but it most likely would have been swallowed by the star as it expanded in size.
Assuming your planet was far enough away from the larger star not to be engulfed or irradiated; you now have a much lower mass object being gravitationally attracted by its now larger partner star; resulting in a deteriorating orbital decay meaning these two stars are going to spiral inwards towards a common centre.&

&: Not all orbits would decay, it is also possible that, if the two stars are far enough away, or close enough together, you'd just get the lower mass star being ejected out of the system due to gravity assist
